# if answered x times correctly in a row, display a message

Tags: python

I'm working on a game for my assignment and I'm stuck on a part where I need to display a message like "Great you are a master at this" IF the user answers correctly 5 times in a row, what I did was something like this :

```
if correct_guesses == 5 and incorrect_guesses == 0 :
    print("""CONGRATULATIONS! You have figured it  all out Great work mate!!""")
```

I've already set up strings that record correct and incorrect guesses for the answers

Right now my code will execute the code and print if the correct guesses equal to 5 but if I get a single guess wrong it will not display, any help?

Comment: Can you clearify a bit more on what you want to do when the player makes one mistake

Comment: If you get wrong once `incorrect_guesses` will not be equal to `0` anymore so the condition will not hold. You don't even need `incorrect_guesses`, just set `correct_guesses` to `0` whenever an answer is wrong... BTW it is better to post a [mre]

Comment: You would want to add the rest of the code in order to increase the chance for a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the counter every time the answer is wrong. The structure can look like this:

```
game_is_running = True # we run the game as long as this is True
counter = 0
while game_is_running:
  was_correct = ask_question() # ask_question() is a function that prints the question and check if it was answered correctly. It correct, return True otherwise return False
  if was_correct: # if the answer was correct, we increase the counter
    counter += 1
  else: # if it was false, we reset it to 0 (we need 5 IN A ROW, right?)
    counter = 0
  if counter == 5: # if we had 5 correct answers in a row, we print and then the game is finished
    print("CONGRATULATIONS! You have figured it all out! Great work mate!!")
    game_is_running = False
```

Comment: Thank you this concept worked perfectly, It was so simple idk why I couldn't think of this haha!

Comment: It's all hard in the beginning. You'll get the hang of it really soon. Keep it up! :) That was a quite well asked question by the way.